# Condição para não enviar campo no ajax

Tags: jquery

Olá!

Existe alguma forma para não enviar o campo senha via ajax, caso este esteja vazio ?

Da forma que está, está enviando como vazio e substituíndo o valor do campo por vazio, então gostaria de enviar este campo, somente se for diferente de vazio.

```js
function form_objeto() {    
    var senha = $('#txt_senha').val();
    if (senha !== null){        
        _obj_operador.nome     = $('#txt_nome').val();
        _obj_operador.cpf      = remove_mascara($('#txt_cpf').val());
        _obj_operador.login    = $('#txt_login').val();
        _obj_operador.senha    = $('#txt_senha').val();
        _obj_operador.situacao = $('#sel_situacao').val();

    } else {
        _obj_operador.nome     = $('#txt_nome').val();
        _obj_operador.cpf      = $('#txt_cpf').val();
        _obj_operador.login    = $('#txt_login').val();
        _obj_operador.situacao = $('#sel_situacao').val();

    }
}
//Função Salvar
function salvar() {
    form_objeto();
    if (salvar_operador()) {        
     atualizar_tabela();
     $('#modal_operador').modal('hide');
 toastr.success('Operador salvo com sucesso');
     }
}
//Método Salvar
function salvar_operador() {
     var url;
     if(_metodo_salvar == 'novo') {
 url = "operador/novo";
     } else {  
 url = "operador/atualizar";
     }
 
 $('#btn_salvar').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Salvando');
 $('#btn_salvar').attr('disabled', true);
 
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        datatype: 'json',  
  url : url,
  data: { 'objeto': JSON.stringify(_obj_operador) },
        success: (function (data) {
            _obj_operador = data;            
   $('#btn_salvar').html('<i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar');
            $('#btn_salvar').attr('disabled', false);
            limpar_modal();
            ret = true;
  }),
        error: (function (erro) {
            //TrataErroAjax(erro);
   alert(erro);
            ret = false;
  })
 });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem sim, mas considere por essa validação em seu *backend*, é mais seguro, e você pode criar outras validações além dessa... você pode remove uma propriedade de um objeto usando o `delete`.

```
function form_objeto() {    
 var senha = $('#txt_senha').val();
 if (senha !== null){        
    _obj_operador.nome     = $('#txt_nome').val();
    _obj_operador.cpf      = remove_mascara($('#txt_cpf').val());
    _obj_operador.login    = $('#txt_login').val();
    _obj_operador.senha    = $('#txt_senha').val();
    _obj_operador.situacao = $('#sel_situacao').val();

 } else {
    delete _obj_operador.senha; //aqui você está removendo a senha

    _obj_operador.nome     = $('#txt_nome').val();
    _obj_operador.cpf      = $('#txt_cpf').val();
    _obj_operador.login    = $('#txt_login').val();
    _obj_operador.situacao = $('#sel_situacao').val();

 }
}
```